# Vim ftplugin executes c.vim instead of cpp.vim for C++ files

Tags: vim, ftplugin

I am learing Vim and I want have set it up as IDE by mapping F5 key to compilation command which is decided by the filetype.

My `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim`:

```
map <F5> :w<CR>:!clang % -o %:r.out && ./%:r.out<CR>
```

My `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
map <F5> :w<CR>:!clang++ -ggdb -pthread -std=c++11 % -o %:r.out && ./%:r.out<CR>
```

When I open a C++ file (with `.cpp` extension) and hit F5, the command from `c.vim` is executed. Why is this happening?

When I remove the file `c.vim`, then Vim loads `cpp.vim` and works as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cpp ftplugin that comes with vim has the following line:

```
runtime! ftplugin/c.vim ftplugin/c_*.vim ftplugin/c/*.vim
```

Which means it is going to source the `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim`.

A way to overcome this is to put your mappings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` and `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` files.

But your problems don't stop there:

- You are using `:map` where you probably want to at least supply a mode. `nmap`
- You also should probably be using `noremap` so it would become `nnoremap`
- Your mapping is global so it will stomp over your `<f5>` everytime you open a `cpp` and switch to a `c` file. You should make it local to the specific buffer. `nnoremap <buffer>`
- You should probably also be setting `makeprg` accordingly so you can take advantage of `:make` and the quickfix list. e.g. `setlocal makprg clang\ %\ -o\ %:r.out`

For more help see:

```
:h :map
:h :map-local
:h 'makeprg'
:h :make
:h quickfix
```

Answer (score 5):

If you move your file into the `/after/ftplugin/` folder, your C specific instructions will still be executed on your C++ files. But your C++ instructions will be executed after the C ones.

If you want to avoid this behaviour, add this at the beginning of your `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim` file

```
if (&ft != 'c')
    finish
endif
```